# Google PlaceAutocompleteFragment crashes with error

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-places-api

In my application homepage The `google place` auto complete `fragment` opens on a button press inside a dialog bar and the location is used for a search query. The problem is when I try to change the location by pressing the button again the application crashes with the following error.

```
*android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
Duplicate id 0x7f0e00db, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment*
```

This is the button press activity and the method that it calls.

```
case R.id.text_area:
            EditLocation();
            break;

private void EditLocation() {

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.area);
    dialog.setTitle("Please enter the location");
    PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);


    ((EditText)autocompleteFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_input)).setHint("Search Location");
    //((EditText)autocompleteFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_input)).setTextSize(10.0f);
    //txtlocation=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.dialogLocationText);

    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(this);
    Button dialogButtonSave = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    dialogButtonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //area=dialogLocation.getText().toString();
            location.setText(area);
            dialog.dismiss();
            //autocompleteFragment.setText("");

        }
    });
    dialog.show();


}
```

Following is the xml code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight=".335"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnOK"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:text="OK"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_orange"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Following are screenshots of how the button and fragment operate.

[image: Searchbar]

[image: Fraggment]

Following is the logcat

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.itcastle.kleanify, PID: 3659
>                     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>                         at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
>                         at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:512)
>                         at com.itcastle.kleanify.WelcomeHomeTemp.EditLocation(WelcomeHomeTemp.java:533)
>                         at com.itcastle.kleanify.WelcomeHomeTemp.onClick(WelcomeHomeTemp.java:453)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>                         at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
>                         at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:512) 
>                         at com.itcastle.kleanify.WelcomeHomeTemp.EditLocation(WelcomeHomeTemp.java:533) 
>                         at com.itcastle.kleanify.WelcomeHomeTemp.onClick(WelcomeHomeTemp.java:453) 
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>                      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #24: Duplicate id 0x7f0e00db, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment
>                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2205)
>                         at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:98)
>                         at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5546)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:36)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:75)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>                         at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
>                         at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:512) 
>                         at com.itcastle.kleanify.WelcomeHomeTemp.EditLocation(WelcomeHomeTemp.java:533) 
>                         at com.itcastle.kleanify.WelcomeHomeTemp.onClick(WelcomeHomeTemp.java:453) 
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3659 SIG: 9
>   Application terminated.

I have gone through many questions and almost everywhere the answer is to add some lines of code inside `onDestroyView()` which I dont have. On the first click the fragment works perfectly, the problem is when I press the button again to change the location the application completely crushes. Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: edited the question. logcat added. Thanks.

Comment: found any solution? @HasanSawan

Comment: Not yet. @MayankBhatnagar

Comment: I got this working now if you are still searching for it, i can post my calling dialog method along with xml

Comment: could you please. thanks. @MayankBhatnagar

Answer (score 2):

try this in your map fragment:

```
 public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = (fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.remove(fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Comment: where shall I put this? Inside Editlocation() method?

Comment: Inside your place autocomplete fragment class..it is a delegate method of the fragment like onCreate()

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code for the same dialog_xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="1dp"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#fff">


<RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_geofence"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
        tools:context="in.gpstracar.gpstracker.GeofenceActivity">

        <Button
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            fontPath="fonts/arial.ttf"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/addGeofenceBtn"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/dismissbutton1"

             />

        <Button
            android:text="Select"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            fontPath="fonts/arial.ttf"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/setRadiusEditText"
            android:id="@+id/submit_buttom" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="53dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Dialog_Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            fontPath="fonts/arial.ttf"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

And Inflating_Dialog in activity

```
private void OpeningDialog(){

    final SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment places ;
    dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.geo_fence_dialog);


     places= (SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

    places.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), place.getName() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), status.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    Button submitbutton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.submit_buttom);
    submitbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FragmentTransaction ft2 = getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            ft2.remove(getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment));
            ft2.commit();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dismissbutton1);
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentTransaction ft2 = getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            ft2.remove( getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment));
            ft2.commit();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

Now Just call the method `OpeningDialog()` Things to keep in mind using this you must set your dialog to `setcancelable` to `false` and give a button closing the dialog and removing the `fragment` on that. 
If you want to set `setcancelable` to `true` then you should handle removing of fragment on that, if you don't remove the fragment it will give the error when inflating the second time.

If any query, let me know.